# Local video tanscoding platform

Tags: php, ruby, video-streaming, video-processing, video-encoding

I was search for a video platform which I can use as a web-service and install locally on my local server to my PHP website.

I know we can run PHP shell commands but I need to implement a solid system with the Transcoder.

So, it should provide a API using REST or SOAP to convert videos, convert videos in efficient way. Create video thumbnails. If it a ruby or Python then it would be great and should be a free and open source one.

I could see those Software on Github, seems its good but having limitations. https://github.com/streamio/streamio-ffmpeg.

Is this a bad idea to use Perl or Python written application using with PHP? what are the available FOS software

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this a bad idea to use Perl or Python written application using with PHP?

A bad idea?  No.  But it can be annoying sometimes.

If you *really* want to use a web service for this instead of just calling `exec`/[`proc_open`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) like the rest of the world, you can go ahead and do that without too much concern.

Another option available to you is [Gearman](http://gearman.org/) a distributed work queue/RPC service with [bindings for many languages, including PHP, Python and Ruby](http://gearman.org/index.php?id=download#client_worker_apis).  You can easily write a daemon in Ruby that uses that ffmpeg wrapper, and call methods directly from your PHP code.  Thanks to how Gearman works, you can easily scale out the video encoding services by just adding more workers.

Comment: Thanks for that idea. Basically what I want to have is Rest WS. Its light weight. I will read more about the Gearman. But is it light weighted to use?

Comment: Gearman is very light-weight for what it does, and remarkably fast.  To be frank, given the raw power that video encoding requires, trying to pick a "light weight" method to call the encoding is probably premature optimization.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use FFMPEG binary for conversion/thumb extraction with command line like exec() in PHP

Comment: I do want to skip using exec(), cause when I run it in Web Server, its too processor intensive. U know PHP does not well in threadding so though of using Ruby or Python to balance the load on the server. That is the basic idea what I have.

Comment: Transcoding wideo i such processor intensive task, that doing exec in PHP() is meaningless in this situation.